# Are there differences between weak convergence and convergence in the weak topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

In some book I found incongruences in notation that are misleading, so the following question arises:

**are weak convergence and convergence in the weak topology always the same thing?**

(the same for the weak-$\star$ convergence)

I know that a theorem states the following

> **Theorem.** Assume $X$ is a Banach space, $\sigma( X, X')$ the weak topology on $X$. Then $x_n \overset{\sigma(X,X')}{\longrightarrow} x$ iff $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ in $\mathbb K$ for all $f \in X'$ when $n\to \infty$.

and

> **Definition.** Assume $X$ is a Banach space, $\{ x_n \} \subseteq X$ *converges weakly* iff there exists $x \in X$ such that $\langle f, x_n \rangle \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \langle f, x \rangle$ for all $f \in X'$. In this case we say that $x$ is the *weak limit* of $\{ x_n \}$.

So I think that when we write $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ or $x_n \overset{\sigma(X,X')}{\longrightarrow} x$ we mean the same, with the only difference that we can use weak convergence also without defining the weak topology. Am I right?

Comment: You're correct; but, your Definition needs "for all $f\in X^*$" added.